# $state.go Failed to instantiate module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot get `$state.go('dashboard')` to work. I get the error:

```
Failed to instantiate module app.controllers.login due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/nomod?p0=app...
```

When defined routes I get no errors. What I'm I doing wrong?

I have also tried `$stateProvider` and get the same error.

**This is my controller...**

App.js

```
    var app = angular.module('dashboardApp', [
    "ngRoute",
    "ngAnimate",
    "ngTouch",
    "mobile-angular-ui",
    "ui.router",
    "app.factories.storage",
    "app.controllers.main",
    "app.controllers.login",
    "angular-loading-bar"



]);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: STATIC_URL + "html/company/login.html",
            controller: "loginController"


        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: STATIC_URL + "html/company/dashboard.html"


        })


});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers.login', [
    "app.factories.http",
    "ui.router",

])
    .controller("loginController", ['$scope', "$location", "httpTokens", "httpFactory", "toaster", "$state",
        function ($scope, $location, httpTokens, httpFactory, toaster, $state ) {


            $scope.actionLoginCompanyUser = function () {
                var post_data = {username: $scope.user.email, password: $scope.user.password};

                httpTokens.createAccessTokens(post_data)
                    .then(function (responce) {

                        if (responce.status == 200) {
                            $state.go('dashboard')
                        }
                        else {
                            toaster.pop('error', "Incorrect Credentials", "Incorrect Email/Password");
                        }

                    })
            }


        }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined the route.

```
angular.module('app.controllers.login', ["app.factories.http","ui.router"])
     .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
                .state('dashboard', {
                    url: "/dashboard",
                    views: {
                        "view": {
                            templateUrl: "views/something.html"
                        }
                    }
                });
```

This should work!

If you want something like a re-route to the login page, which I assume, you can also add the following in the config:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("login");
```

What this does is, if someone tries to go to a route which doesn't exist it will route you back to login.

**NOTE:**

If you are using `$q` or `$timeout`, try using `$location.path('/dashboard');` instead.

More info on that particular behaviour: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/916

Comment: This is my controller not my app.js and the app.js includes already the ui.router

Comment: May I ask why you define ['ui.router'] in your controller then ? Is your app.js as the code I provided?

Comment: I am trying to just redirect to a page name by name, not defined the routes :)

Comment: Can you try to use $location.path('/dashboard'); ? And see if that does work.

Comment: Already thought so! Do you use any promises? $q maybe? or any $timeout?

Comment: Yes, how does this impact things? I use $q

Comment: It's about how $q handles the resolve. You can try to $q.flush() before or after you use $state.go(), I don't know the exact reason. I had this issue myself with a heartbeat that redirects you if you session has expired! I will edit my answer for future usage.